# fetching and passing params in react navigation

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, fetch, react-navigation

On Press of a button I need to pass params to another screen where value of that button is fetched, code below;

screen:1

```
    <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Quiz", { fetch: "history" })}
            style={styles.button}
          >
            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>History</Text>
   
</TouchableOpacity>
```

screen:2

```
const Quiz = ({ navigation, route }) => {
const { fetch } = route.params;

const getQuiz = async () => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    const url = `https://herokuapp.com/q/${fetch}`;
    const res = await fetch(url);
    const data = await res.json();
    setQuestions(data.results);
    setOptions(generateOptionsAndShuffle(data.results[0]));
    setIsLoading(false);
  };
```

But during the fetching I get the following error

```
[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: fetch is not a function. (In 'fetch(url)', 'fetch' is "history")]
```

I have tried using timeout but that is not working, is there a better option.

Comment: Does it work when you rename the param "fetch" to "test" and then change the occurences in getQuiz to test, but leave "await fetch(url)" as it is?

Comment: You create a variable named `fetch` that overrides the built in `fetch` function. Name your variable something else to avoid the conflict.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `fetch` is a native function in javascript (see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)).

You should rename the param to another name like `quizz`.

screen:1

```
<TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Quiz", { quizz: "history" })}
        style={styles.button}
      >
        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>History</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

screen:2

```
const Quiz = ({ navigation, route }) => {
  const { quizz } = route.params;

  const getQuiz = async () => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    const url = `https://herokuapp.com/q/${quizz}`;
    const res = await fetch(url);
    const data = await res.json();
    setQuestions(data.results);
    setOptions(generateOptionsAndShuffle(data.results[0]));
    setIsLoading(false);
  };
```